# Opendkim doesn't sign emails sending from external clients

Tags: sendmail, freebsd, signing, dkim

I've setup opendkim with my sendmail and it looks like everything works correctly, but it signs only those messages that sent locally (from webmail client or automatic subscriptions). when I try  to send message using email-client (e.g. The Bat), maillog shows the following

```
Apr 21 11:48:02 d3355 opendkim[57808]: v3L8m2jE059174: [xx.167.249.178] [xx.167.249.178] not internal
Apr 21 11:48:02 d3355 opendkim[57808]: v3L8m2jE059174: not authenticated
Apr 21 11:48:02 d3355 opendkim[57808]: v3L8m2jE059174: no signature data
```

where xx.167.249.178 is my local IP address. If I add it to TrustedHosts, then opendkim starts to sign messages sent from this IP. But is't not a solution of course, I can't add IP addresses each time I send messages from new network.

Comment: Can you post your dkim.conf

Comment: I am facing the same issue, were you able to solve it?